# rails 3 custom date won't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a complete rails noob, so there's probably something very simple I'm missing here. I have these little tweet-type things called microposts, and I want each micropost to have a release date set by the user. My form looks ok and doesn't show any errors in the browser when I create a new micropost, but the release date isn't being saved in the database. In my form to create a new micropost, I have this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :release_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :release_date, :size => 10 %>
</div>
```

In my database schema, I have this:

```
  create_table "microposts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "release_date"
  end
```

I made the release_date attribute accessible in my Micropost model like so:

```
attr_accessible :content, :release_date
```

And my create method in my Micropost controller looks like this:

```
def create
  @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
  if @micropost.save
    flash[:success] = "New event created."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
     render 'pages/home'
  end
end
```

Everything else saves just fine. It's only the release date that seems to be ignored. This is just a wild guess, but is rails ok with something like 10/25/2011 being saved as a datetime? Or is that supposed to be saved as a string and then parsed into a proper datetime format?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of info missing here to evaluate. The params hash probably doesn't have the value, or it isn't hashed in a way expected by rails.

In your User model, do you have:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :microposts
```

Also, you'll want to look up tutorials on form_for and fields_for in rails.

Answer (score 0):

Likely the format you are entering the date in isn't getting cast as a datetime properly:

```
def Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation_on_create :convert_release_date_to_datetime

  private

    def convert_release_date_to_datetime
      self.release_date = Time.parse(release_date)
    end
end
```